# How do a query where, joining a table, the field can get a value from fields A or B with Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, join, where-clause

I got two tables

**Players** (Id - Name)

**Games** (TournamentID - Player1 - Player2 - Result)

I'm trying to join the tables in a main one, named "Tennis Tournament" where it shows each game such as (PlayerName 1 vs PlayerName 2)

My query is working just with one ID1_G(Player1) but I don't know to get ID2_G(Player2) too.

Next syntax is which I'm trying with but it is not working...

```
$tournament = $this->games->where('ID_T_G', $id)
            ->join('rounds', 'rounds.ID_R', '=', 'games_wta.ID_R_G')
            ->join('players_wta', 'players_wta.ID_P', '=', 'games_wta.ID1_G', 'or', 'games_wta.ID2_G')->get();
```

Images are always better than words so I'll show you (if you didn't understand me before) what I want to do.

[image]

Please, any advice!

Comment: would be great to have the CREATE statements of your tables.

Comment: I don't have it, I created the tables manually.

Comment: join twice on the same table on respective keys.

Comment: I already tried like that, it shows this error:       SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'players_wta' (SQL: select * from `games_wta` inner join `rounds` on `rounds`.`ID_R` = `games_wta`.`ID_R_G` inner join `players_wta` on `players_wta`.`ID_P` = `games_wta`.`ID1_G` inner join `players_wta` on `players_wta`.`ID_P` = `games_wta`.`ID2_G` where `ID_T_G` = 1)

Comment: As @wanted has mentioned, could you please post the table schema? You can export the DB to generate the SQL file with the schema, then update your question with the schema.

Comment: I did already right now

Answer (score 0):

I finally I got it working with the raw SQL statement below:

```
SELECT
    P1.NAME_P AS Player1,
    P2.NAME_P AS Player2
    FROM games_wta As G
    INNER JOIN players_wta AS P1
        ON G.ID1_G = P1.ID_P
    INNER JOIN players_wta AS P2
        ON G.ID2_G = P2.ID_P;
```